# Laravel 8 passport OAuth api "error": "invalid_client",

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-8, laravel-passport

i try to test oauth on passport using laravel 8 but it gave me this error:

```
  {
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Client authentication failed",
    "message": "Client authentication failed"
  }
```

this is screen shot of passport

[image]

Comment: what does GET /oauth/clients request return?

Comment: 200 OK Thanks a lot but i need to do it with post method and with post method it says 419unknown status

Comment: does it rreturn the cline id for the auth you are typing

Comment: no, its just returning a html file with 419 unkown error

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are working with Passport, make sure you have followed the steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#loading-keys-from-the-environment). Looks like you have missed the publishing of the keys from passport config `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config`. Once again if it is a fresh installation, you just need to follow the steps mentioned in the documentation to setup Passport and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same error in one of my project on which I was working on, and just by googling I came to this post. I also tried the proposed answer but it wasn't work for me so I gone through with given parameters. My use case was a bit different in which I was on password authorized screen and facing the same error as you have. I was just passing the data in query string. So I just matched my query string data with the one I have in the database and my issue is resolved now. Try this in your case as well and hoping your issue will also fixed. **This error is less or more depending upon the posted data**.

Answer (score 0):

Also just facing this issue - remember to ensure your callback URLs are correct (which in my case meant running `valet secure` because I'd specified https and it wasn't!)

Big rabbit hole, because of course everything else looks correct, and this is automatic.